# Unix IPC sockets send/recv sync

Tags: c++, sockets, unix

I'm using local a Unix socket to communicate between two different processes. Thing is, some parts of the code on bth ends take different time to run, and I need `recv` and `send` to be synced across both processes. Is there a way to force `send` and `recv` to wait for the next corresponding line on the opposite process?

Comment: You'll need to be clearer about what you want.  If you need to handle sending and receiving at the same time, then you'll need to either use multiple threads or use one of the [`select(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) or [`poll(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) system calls.

Answer (score 1):

You must implement a protocol. After all, you can not be sure that the sockets are in sync. For example you could send one package with 100 bytes and then receive two ore even more packages adding it up.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `recv()` will block (wait) until there are data to read, while `send()` will block until there is space in the buffer to write to.  For most applications, this is enough synchronisation (if you design your protocol sanely).

So I recommend you just think about the details of how your communication will work, and try it out.  Then if there is still a problem, come back with a question that is as specific as possible.

Comment: I've been basing my code aroud this, placing dummy `recv()` to make the program stop from time to time. However, if it takes some time, I get the error `recv: Connection reset by peer`. Does `recv` has some kind of timeout value when waiting?

Comment: Use `setsockopt` (I get this from man pages, I haven't tried it myself).  However the `socket(7)` page says the default is to have no timeout.